# image tag in update panel

Tags: c#, updatepanel, image

I am new to .net. I am writing a new application in which I have to show a slide show of images with button controls. the code is

```
 <div id = "slideshow" style = "width:auto" runat="server" align ="center">
            <asp:Label ID = "slideHeader" runat="server" />
                 <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl=" " ID = "img" style="width:90%; height:100%;"/>
            <hr style = "height:20px; border:0px; color:White"  />
                    <asp:Button id="prev" Text="Previous" OnClick = "prevClick" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:Button id="next" Text="Next" OnClick = "nextClick" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:Button id="start" Text="Start" OnClick = "startClick" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:Button id="stop" Text="Stop" OnClick = "stopClick" runat="server"/>
            </div>
```

The code behind for the buttons is

```
protected void nextClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

img.ImageUrl = path; 

}
```

I dont know how to use update panel for this. when I used update panel tag around img tag, it is showing that update panel does not has the property img. How can i achive this?

Comment: You'll need to post some code if you want an answer. Also if possible migrate to ASP.NET MVC 4 instead of using ASP.NET Pages

Comment: @Gabriel : I used updatepanel tag around <asp:Image> tag. I am just beginner in .Net.

Comment: @Gabriel : My page is loading completely even if i click on next button. I just want the image to be changed when I click on next or previous buttons.

Comment: I would use only HTML, JavaScript and CSS for this task. A good start: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+slideshow